# Php: I need to insert one & within my mysql database

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with the ampersand symbol, because I've to allow user to insert page_title within database.
The problem is that in my mother language many companies have the symbol in their names like per example "Santos & Filhos".

The question is, how can I insert this, without break my database and without opening security issues?

using this the database gets broken

```
$title = preg_replace('/&/', '&amp;', $title);
$final_title = utf8_encode($title);
```

I'm using utf8_encode because of the other accents like á or ã

Thanks, hope you can help me here

---

### EDIT

ok, first thanks to all, most of you were wright, mysql_real_escape_string is indeed one of the best options, if not the best.

I discovered that I was missing one escape (in query) before  post my variables to be processed by php and inserted within the database.

So I manage to get my & but now I can't manage to have accents...

So far my php code looks like this

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$sql = "UPDATE bodytable SET body_title = '".utf8_encode($title)."'";
```

and then in my frontage I've

```
utf8_decode($row['body_title']);
```

the result is

```
<title>Santos & Filhos - Repara?es de autom?veis</title>
```

Comment: What does `using this the database gets broken` mean?

Comment: What type of database ? Mysql, sql server, oracle?

Comment: You don't need preg_replace for this, str_replace will do.  You don't need str_replace for this, htmlentities and htmlspecialchars exist purely for this kind of substitution.  You don't need htmlentities or htmlspecialchars because inserting an & into your database won't break anything, you just need to remember to apply htmlentities or htmlspecialchars when you're outputting it when you don't want it parsed as HTML.  So really, just store the & as is.

Comment: In addition to @GordonM , mysql_real_escape_string() helps to change chars which might cause issues.

Comment: You might want to also post more code here, because a & shouldn't be breaking your query.

Answer (score 2):

Escape characters going into the database with something like `mysql_real_escape_string()` or PDO and use `htmlentities()` when displaying it.

This covers securing user input: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an escape character in front of all your special characters you want to insert in the database. Encoding is ok but for example, if the following string was to be added to mysql string field you would get an error.

"special characters don't work"

And you can do this to prevent these errors

"special characters don\'t work"

I belive there is a methods called addslashes(string x) and stripslashes(string x) that will do that for you.

Comment: addslashes and stripslashes are the worst thing for escaping queries. That's what `mysql_real_escape_string()` and parameter binding are for.

Answer (score 0):

$title_to_insert_in_database = $str = addslashes($title);

$title_for_page = htmlspecialchars($title_from_database);